Delayed commandment for immersion of vessels?
In parshas Mattos, Bemidbar 31:19-20 we learn about ritual immersions for people and vessels who went to a war. These laws are taught after the war with Midian. Why did the Torah delay teaching these mitzvos, when it could teach them in parshas Chukas after the wars with Sihon and Og?
